# In 1D, the line element becomes the 1D Riemannian volume form... does the pattern hold for any dimensions?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

The Riemannian volume form is

$$
\omega = \sqrt{|\det g|} dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n
$$

The line element is:

$$
ds=\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}dX^\mu dX^\nu}
$$

---

### 1D:

First, the Riemannian volume form reduces to:

$$
\omega =\sqrt{|\det g|}dx
$$

Second, the line element in 1D. In 1D, the quantities reduces to $g=\pmatrix{g_{xx}}$ and $\det g$= $g_{xx}$ and $\mu,\nu \in \{x\}$. Thus:

$$
\begin{align}
ds&=\sqrt{g_{xx} dX^x dX^x}\\
&=\sqrt{g_{xx} } dX^x \\
&=\sqrt{|\det g| } dx \\
\end{align}
$$

where $dX^x:=dx$.

Consequently, a line element in 1D is equal to the Riemannian volume form in 1D. The line element has a "richer" definition only if the line is embedded into a space of more dimensions.

---

### 2D and above:

The 2D equivalent of the line element is the parametrized surface integral (not sure of the mathematics name, but in physics, it is the same as Nambu-Goto action in general curvilinear coordinates).

First, the Riemannian volume form in 2D is

$$
\omega = \sqrt{|\det g|} dx \wedge dy
$$

Now, the general notation for the p-volume element a p-surface embedded with a larger D-dimensional space is given as follows ([page 19](https://books.google.ca/books?id=WgUkSTJWQacC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=p-brane%20action&source=bl&ots=2Y8x6AlGpg&sig=ACfU3U0-Bqba895YquHA6S9fjWYjLLolMA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpgfmIuIvqAhWDmeAKHXdGBNsQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

$$
d\mu_p = \sqrt{|\det G_{\alpha\beta}| } d^{p+1} x
$$

where

$$
G_{\alpha\beta}= g_{\mu\nu} \partial_\alpha X^\mu \partial_\beta X^\nu
$$

In the 2D case, this reduces to

$$
g_{\mu\nu}=\pmatrix{g_{xx} & g_{xy}\\ g_{yx} & g_{yy}}
$$

and $G_{\alpha\beta} \to G_{xy}$ becomes:

$$
G_{xy}=\pmatrix { 
g_{xx}\partial_x X^x \partial_x X^x & g_{xy} \partial_x X^x \partial_y X^y \\
g_{yx}\partial_y X^y \partial_x X^x & g_{yy} \partial_y X^y \partial_y X^y
}
$$

and the determinant is:

$$
\begin{align}
\det G_{xy}&=g_{xx}\partial_x X^x \partial_x X^x g_{yy} \partial_y X^y \partial_y X^y -  g_{xy} \partial_x X^x \partial_y X^y g_{yx}\partial_y X^y \partial_x X^x\\
&=(g_{xx} g_{yy} -  g_{xy}  g_{yx}) ( \partial_x X^x \partial_y X^y)^2\\
&=\det g_{xy}( \partial_x X^x \partial_y X^y)^2
\end{align}
$$

Consequently, the volume element becomes:

$$
\begin{align}
d\mu_p&=\sqrt{|\det g_{xy}|}\partial_x X^x \partial_y X^y\\
&=\sqrt{|\det g_{xy}|}dxdy
\end{align}
$$

Based on this it certainly does seem like the idea generalizes to n-dimensions.

A few questions on the notation and exactness:

1. I could use a checkup that what I have done is legit.
2. For my derivation to work I need $\partial_x X^x=dx$. Can someone prove this or explain why that is? The way I see it is $\partial_x X^x=\partial X[x,y]^x / \partial x$. It is not clear how the partial derivative of a function ends up to a total derivative $dx$.
3. Where does the wedge product come from? Perhaps the book I referenced abuses the notation? Should $G_{\alpha\beta}$ actually be written:

$$
G_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\mu\nu} (\partial_\alpha X^\mu \wedge \partial_\beta X^\nu)
$$

---

edit:

For question 2, I am wondering if there is another abuse of notation in the definition of $G_{\alpha\beta}$? Should it be:

$$
G_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\mu\nu} (\partial_\alpha X^\mu d\alpha \wedge \partial_\beta X^\nu d\beta)
$$

Then everything would fit neatly --- can anyone confirm?

In this case $\partial_x X^x dx = (\partial X^x /\partial x) dx= (1)dx=dx$

---

edit

actually I just noticed the definition by the author is

$$
d\mu_p = \sqrt{|\det G_{\alpha\beta}| } d^{p+1} x
$$

thus the total differential terms are indeed included in the definition. Moving them inside the definition of $G_{\alpha\beta}$ may make the definition more intuitive because it becomes the generalization of the line element, but it is not notational abuse.

So, question 1 and 3 remains.